# loop not iterating through entire arraylist

Tags: java, android

I'm having a problem where I am trying to iterate through an arraylist which stores restaurant objects but the loop only goes through 3 of the five elements.

I created a test method to illustrate:

```
public void testLoop() {
        ArrayList<Eatery> test = new ArrayList<Eatery>();
        test = eateriesListDefault;
        for(Eatery e : test) {
            MyLog.e(TAG, "Name: " + e.getName());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < eateriesListDefault.size(); i++) {
            MyLog.e(TAG, "Name " + test.get(i).getName());
            test.remove(i);
        }
        for(Eatery e : test) {
            MyLog.e(TAG, "Name " + e.getName());
        }
    }
```

Here test will have 5 eatery objects in it. The first loop succesfully prints 5 of 5 names.
The second loop only removes 3 of the eateries and therefore the last loop prints two names.

I have tried using

```
for(Eatery e : eateriesListDefault) {
            MyLog.e(TAG, "Name: " + e.getName());
            test.remove(e);
}
```

in place of the second loop, however I get a concurrent access error.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: First off, you shouldn't use a `foreach` loop when trying to remove values out of the collection. That is the cause of your concurrent access error. See [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html). Can you also explain why you issue a `new ArrayList` call only to create an assignment on the next line?

Comment: Is it possible for us to see what eateriesListDefault would look like?  Perhaps instead of "for (Eatery e : test)" as the first loop, you should try and mimic your 2nd loop so you can compare apples to apples.  I'm just trying to rule out any indexing problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're calling `eateriesListDefault.size()` in each loop iteration.  At the same time, you're calling `test.remove(i)` which is shorting the array by one every iteration.  Your loop is essentially doing this:

1. i = 0
   size = 5
   Keep going
2. i = 1
   size = 4
   Keep going
3. i = 2
   size = 3
   Keep going
4. i = 3
   size = 2
   stop

If you're goal was to print out the first element of the array then remove it, you could probably get there by this loop:

```
while(!eateriesListDefault.isEmpty()) {
   MyLog.e(TAG, "Name " + test.get(0).getName());
   test.remove(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second loop removes elements from the array while your loop index continues to increase. On the fourth pass, your loop index is 3, but eateriesListDefault.size is 2, so the loop exits.

Try this instead:

```
for ( Iterator<Eatery> it = test.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
   MyLog.e(...)
   it.remove();
}
```

The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the list is modified during iteration in any way other than by calling Iterator.remove(). See the [Iterator.remove() documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29).

Also, you may want to make a copy of the default list. Your "test =" statement is just making a new reference to the same list.

```
test = new ArrayList<Eatery>( eateriesListDefault );
```

Comment: In an extension explanation: if you consider how the loop works you get multiple steps: step 1, list size = 5, remove an element. step 2, list size = 4 remove an element. step 3, loop size = 3, quit.